# React-chosen raising error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React-chosen (https://github.com/chenglou/react-chosen, a React wrapper for the jQuery Chosen plugin, https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).
I get a problem with the multiple select element.

If I do something like this (inside a `React.createClass` call):

```
    loadDataFromServer: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/users/',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var option = data[i];
                    var val = [option.id];
                    this.state.options.push(
                        <option key={i} value={val}>{option.name}</option>
                    );
                }
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: [], options: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.loadDataFromServer();
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <form className="well base_well new_task_well" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Chosen width="300px" data-placeholder="Select..." multiple>
                    {this.state.options}
                </Chosen>
                <button type="button" className="btn add_button"  id="add_new_task_btn" type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
         )
     }
```

then everything works fine (I basically do an AJAX call to the API and build a dropdown select list with possible multiple values based on the result).

However, to reduce code-size, I wanted to build the select list as a separate component, as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25818571/2486678

I build the component like this:

```
var multipleSelect = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        url: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            options: []
        }
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            success: this.successHandler
        })
    },
    successHandler: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var option = data[i];
            this.state.options.push(
                <option key={i} value={option.value}>{option.name}</option>
            );
        }
    },
    render: function() {
       return this.transferPropsTo(
            <Chosen width="300px" data-placeholder="Select..." multiple>
                {this.state.options}
            </Chosen>
       )
   }
});
```

and then, in a parent component's `render` method, I "insert" the `multipleSelect` component into a form:

```
<multipleSelect url="/api/places"
    value={this.state.place_childSelectValue} onChange={this.place_changeHandler}
/>
```

While that works fine for `Chosen` elements with only a single value possible (without the `multiple` prop passed), if I try this approach for lists with multiple possible values, I get this error:

**"Warning: The `value` prop supplied to < select> must be an array if `multiple` is true. Check the render method of `Chosen`."**

Any ideas why that is happening>

Comment: Is `place_childSelectValue` an array?  If not, it needs to be.  Also you shouldn't store descriptors in state, you should store the data.  `successHandler: function(data){ this.setState({data: data}) }` and create the `<option>`s in render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use multi-select so the `value` prop must be an array (for **multi** select)
use an array for `place_childSelectValue`, or just put him into single element array:

```
[this.state.place_childSelectValue]
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to set `place_childSelectValue` to an empty array in `componentDidMount`.